# Apache : Directory is still accessible even though options -index is specified

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have OHS 11g with apache 2.2 bundled with it. In OHS home, there is folder "icons" and sub folder "small" which are accessible through http request. To disable browsing on these directories, I have included below setting in httpd.conf and restarted the server.  But still these 2 folders are accessible from UI. How to resolve this?

Options -Indexes

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use .htaccess file?

Make sure file reads:

`order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from [your.IP]`

then just 'service apache2 restart'

Comment: Yes. httpd.conf file is accessible. I will make your suggestions to this file and let you know if it works.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear. '.htaccess' is a separate file which apache will read on restart. Search google for .htaccess and learn from the examples.